Looking for PDO Informix extension for PHP 8.3
I'm trying to connect my Php 8.3 (x64) to IBM Informix database.
I have found pre-compiled versions of the extension for PHP 8.0 and 8.1 but it doesn't work with PHP 8.3.
Does anyone have this extension pre-compiled to make available in PHP 8.3 version?

Did you tried with the PDO 1.3.6? https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX

to get it working i would need to build it. I'm looking for a pre-compiled dll before going to that way of building it

I've just compiled the pecl available version (1.3.6) for php 8.3.4 and tested successfully with informix csdk 4.10fc8de x64.
Sharing the dll below to help others that may need it.
https://github.com/evandrosimenes/usefulstuff/tree/main/php_pdo_informix
